# $parent and $ current in orientDB query

Tags: orientdb

I read it on orientDB documentation but can't get a hold of it.
It would be great if someone could explain the use of $parent and $current in detail.
In a few examples I tried $parent.$parent.$current and $parent.$current, both give the same results which I feel should not happen. Below are my assumption:

1. $current gives access to the record/node currently being processed
2. $parent gives access to the parent of current record/node being processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second assumption is wrong. It gives you access to the variables of the parent query (useful when calling traverse in a sub-query as stated [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Traverse.html)).

An example:

```
create class User extends V    
create class Follows extends E

create vertex User set name = 'u1'
create vertex User set name = 'u2'
create vertex User set name = 'u3'    

create edge Follows from (select from User where name = 'u1') to (select from User where name = 'u2')
create edge Follows from (select from User where name = 'u2') to (select from User where name = 'u3')


select $all from User
let $all = ( traverse out('Follows') from $parent.$current)
```

Comment: select $all from (select from user where name like '%bob%')
let $all = ( traverse out('Follows') from $parent.$current) , is this correct as well?

Comment: Didn't test but it seems okay.

Comment: I have a similar query, and it works only when I do $parent.$parent.$current . Not sure why

Comment: And $parent.$parent.$parent.$current? I'm guessing that the base query is parent of itself.

Comment: May be I am stretching it too much. $parent.$parent.$parent.$current does work but $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$current doesn't. Too confusing.

Comment: Maybe you were expecting to receive a warning or even an error, but if it works when you use it right I don't see the problem. I guess your question is answered.